# res.json not sending a json response

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a simple "Ticket" model that looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var alias = require('mongoose-aliasfield');

var ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    d: { type: String, alias: 'description', required: true, trim: true },
    t: { type: Date, alias: 'eventdate', required: true }
});

ticketSchema.plugin(alias);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', ticketSchema);
```

I'm trying to return all the existing tickets as json using Express Router:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Ticket = require('../models/ticket');

router.get('/', function (req,res) {
    Ticket.find({}, function(err, tickets) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
        return res.status(200).json(tickets);
    });
});
```

For some reason, the response is coming back as an array of objects with a Content-Type of "text/html":

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1826
ETag: W/"722-szU3qBkszFjaLqHo4B0UZA"
Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 08:23:32 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I believe I should be getting back json with a Content-Type of "application/json"... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `res.json(tickets);` instead of `res.status(200).json(tickets);`

Answer (score 0):

try comment out `ticketSchema.plugin(alias);`

i am using  below packages but no alias plugin

"express": "4.13.4",
"mongoose": "4.4.10",